Dealing with custom encryption in laravel on some columns in database and get data by 'where' clause
I have a table that one of its column should have encrypted data. I have custom encryption functions in laravel for this purpose. In related model, I use these functions to encrypt and decrypt data while reading or storing in item column:
public function setItemAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['item'] = Crypto::EncryptData($value);
}
public function getItemAttribute($value) {
    return Crypto::DecryptData($value);
}

By these functions, data is stored as encrypted data in database and is read as decrypted data from database automatically. But the problem appear when I want to use where clause in my queries (Specially when LIKE is used.):
$data = Data::select('col1', 'item', 'col2')->where('item', 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%')->get();

Query with where clause on col1 or col2 which is not encrypted is fine, but for item column it has no result.
What should I do for resolving this problem?

Don't encrypt the column with Laravel encryption if you want to do wildcard searches on it.

@apokryfos But I need it. How about using encryption in database? and use AES_DECRYPT(column_name, 'encryption_key') LIKE '%$value%' in my where clause?

That would work if when you store the data you call AES_ENCRYPT which will need to be done manually.

@apokryfos Yeap! I should use MySQL encryption functions in every read and store commands by this way.

If you just want to secure data so it's not readable in cases of data leaks of your database file-system then you can also use at rest encryption, otherwise yes you'll need to manually ensure data is encrypted with MySQL functions. You could probably write a trigger to ensure data is always stored encrypted so you don't have to call the encryption functions manually via Laravel code
